# How to get ArrayList from a custom view in Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, view, nullpointerexception

I have a Java class Class1 which extends View as follows:

```
public class Class1 extends View
{   private ArrayList<SomeClass> list;
    public Class1(Context context,AttributeSet attrs)
    {   super(context,attrs);
        list=new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {   canvas.drawSomething();
    }

    void FunctiontoaddelementstoArrayList()
    {   list.add(SomeClass);
    }

    public ArrayList<SomeClass> getList()
    {    return this.list;
    }
}
```

and I am adding this view to my layout file using these xml tags,

```
<com.example.Class1
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#FFFFFFFF" />
```

Now in my `mainactivity` class, I want to get the ArrayList that I have in my view class, so is used this code for that:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{   private Class1 class1;
private Button fetch;
private ArrayList<SomeClass> mylist;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
class1=(Class1)findViewById(R.id.myview);
fetch=(Button)findViewById(R.id.fetch);
fetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{   @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {   try
        {   mylist = class1.getList();
            SomeClass S = mylist.get(0);
            Log.v("Got", S.getSomeThing());
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {   e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

}

However, it throws a `NullPointerException` at `mylist.getList();` line, How can I get the ArrayList from my custom view class?

Comment: post the onCreate of your Activity

Comment: In your code snippet mylist is not initialised. Did you mean myview?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: I have confirmed that my ArrayList is not Empty in Class1

Comment: You say you have edited the question, but you are still accessing mylist.getList, not myview.getList - is this right? If so show where mylist is setup.

Comment: Edited, I have noticed that my myview object is Null

Comment: You are probably calling findViewById before the layout has been successfully inflated, but not possible to tell from the code snippet you have posted

Comment: Still not working, Actually my custom view is inside a content_main.xml which is include in my activity_main.xml

Comment: Added MainActivity Class